# Assigning $index to ng-model: AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a kendo multi select widget in my template, the code for which is given below.

```
<div ng-repeat="program in user.programs">
    <label class="label-multi">{{program.name}}:</label>
    <select kendo-multi-select="" k-option-label="'Select Services...'" k-data-text-field="'name'" k-data-value-field="'id'" k-data-source="services" k-ng-model="selectedServices" >
    </select>
</div>
```

Each `user` has several `programs`, and each `program` has some `services`. Now I want to show the services that are already associated with the program i.e `selectedServices` which I initialize in my controller like so:

```
$scope.selectedServices = ["S1","S2"];
```

But the problem is that `selectedServices` vary for each program. I was thinking about doing something like `selectedServices[0]`, `selectedServices[1]` and so on using `$index`. How do I achieve this and how do assign values to these `selectedServices` in my controller? Wouldn't it be an array of arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add a `selectedServices` array to `user.programs`?
For example:

```
$scope.user.programs.selectedServices = ["S1", "S2"];
```

Comment: You are a genius and I'm an idiot. You made my life about 10x time easier, thanks man!

Comment: Glad to be helpful... ;-)